# Can't compile properly with lualatex as www-data

Tags: laravel, apache, latex

I have a web app in which i would like to be able to compile .tex docs.
I have installed texlive on my VM by executing `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.
My problem is that when i try to compile a .tex with the www-data user, i get this kind of log for my .tex.

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2023.9.5)  15 OCT 2023 18:20
 restricted system commands enabled.
**templateMiseEnPage04bf8b50-b5b5-49c6-bcb7-c6b4523bfebc3.tex
(./templateMiseEnPage04bf8b50-b5b5-49c6-bcb7-c6b4523bfebc3.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries....e/texmf-di
st/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:4145: bad argument #1 to 'find' (
string expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'string.find'
    ...e/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:4145: in main chunk

    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua:96: in local 'loadm
odule'
    .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic.lua:44: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua:96: in local 'loadm
odule'
    .../share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua:106: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...ive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:224: in upvalue 'in
it_main'
    ...ive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:590: in function 'l
uaotfload-init.lua'
    .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:322: in field 'main
'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
<everyjob> ...ring \\def\string \\encodingdefault{OT1}')end }
                                                  \let \f@encoding \encoding...
l.1 
  \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

L3 programming layer <2023-01-16>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable: metric da
ta not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.54 \normalsize
```

As i'm working on a Laravel project, i tried what i found here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480119/lualatex-doesnt-run-when-under-www-data with the Process syntax :

```
        $process = new Process(['/usr/bin/lualatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', $texFile]);
        $process->setEnv(['TEXMFCACHE' => ':/tmp/']);
        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            echo $process->getOutput();
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
```

in order to compile the .tex directly from the app, but i get the same log message.

I guess the first thing would be to manage to compile the .tex by hand in the VM as www-data.

When i run the .tex on the VM as root, all is ok.

Comment: Can you compile the same `.tex` file using a different user?

Comment: Yes, as root it works.